# How to use Httprequest object in FormView?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

i was converting the below function view in class based view :
but the problem was the below login code uses request object . so how to use this request in a form view .

Functional view i wanted to change to class based view :

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = UserLoginForm()


    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserLoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = User.objects.filter(name=username, password=password).first()
            if user is not None:
                request.session['user'] = username
                return redirect('index')

            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Username or password no matched')


    return render(request, 'products_app/login.html', {'form': form})
```

FormView/class based view of the above code i changed to that gives error :

```
class Login(FormView):
    template_name = 'products_app/login.html'
    form_class = UserLoginForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def form_valid(self, form):
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = User.objects.filter(name=username, password=password).first()
            if user is not None:
                request.session['user'] = username
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Username or password no matched')
            super().form_valid(form)
```

here the problem is ,request is not being received unlike in the functional view of above def login(request). so gives error:

```
module 'django.http.request' has no attribute 'session'
```

Comment: Did you enable the session middleware?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes  i have listed 'django.contrib.sessions', in installed_apps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the `request` module as stated in the error. What you actually want is the request instance that invoked the class. Your code should be `self.request`.

I've eliminated all the superfluous code to only show the parts with `request`.

```py
class Login(FormView):
    ...

    def form_valid(self, form):
            ...
            if user is not None:
                self.request.session['user'] = username
            else:
                messages.error(self.request, 'Username or password no matched')
            ...
```